# Нужна помощь с заданием

Tags: java, c++, python, python-3.x, pascal

В логе службы есть N записей, в которых указано, что в i-й момент времени Васина программа потребляла Ai мегабайт памяти. Если в какой-то момент времени потребление памяти программой выросло в два раза или больше по сравнению с предыдущим моментом, значит произошла утечка памяти. Если в какой-то момент времени потребление памяти программой упало в два раза или больше по сравнению с предыдущим моментом, значит программа аварийно завершилась и была перезапущена. Помогите Пете посчитать количество утечек памяти и аварийных завершений его программы.

Comment: С начала было всё нормально сформулировано, я дал ответ. Через некоторое время кто-то отредачил вопрос и обрезал половину. Вопрос - зачем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector < int > v(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) cin >> v[i];

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if(v[i] / v[i-1] >= 2) ++a;
        else if(v[i-1] / v[i] >= 2) ++b;    
    }
    cout << a << ' ' << b;
    return 0;

}
```